# Azure Web App SSL authentication with client certificate - how to diagnose

Tags: authentication, ssl, azure-web-app-service, diagnostics

I want to use mutual authentication with client certificate. But when I switch "Client certificate mode" to Required in Azure Web App configuration, then no requests are reached into my Asp.net core web app.

Is there a way to diagnose why underlying host (IIS?) canceled the request? I tried to enable "Failed request tracing" and "Detailed error messages" but there is nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best Regards, Jindrich Pastorek

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question! Could you please confirm on how you have enabled client certificate,

To set up your app to require client certificates, you can switch On the Require incoming certificate by selecting Configuration > General Settings from the Azure Portal.

From Azure CLI  or you need to set the clientCertEnabled setting for your app to true.

az webapp update --set clientCertEnabled=true --name <app_name> --resource-group <group_name>

Also, when you enable mutual auth for your application, all paths under the root of your app will require a client certificate for access. To allow certain paths to remain open for anonymous access, you can define exclusion paths as part of your application configuration. Exclusion paths can be configured by selecting Configuration > General Settings and defining an exclusion path.

To add to this For ASP.NET, the client certificate is available through the HttpRequest.ClientCertificate property.

You may refer to below doc links for more details on this might be helpful

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#enable-client-certificates

https://msftplayground.com/2016/06/azure-app-service-and-client-certificate-authentication/