# Azure App Service client side certificate exclusion path

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167712/certificate-exclusion-paths-in-azure-app-service) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62893534/azure-web-app-ssl-authentication-with-client-certificate-how-to-diagnose), but I'm wondering if I can inverse the exclusion path? i.e. list the paths that require a client side cert. It's not practical to exclude all paths, because it's a lot.

Same for other services. If we have mixed client-side-cert required and none, do we always need to create separate services, e.g. App Service, Api Management etc. ? Sort of annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this feature not available. Only one way to implement this that is  [Exclude paths from requiring authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#exclude-paths-from-requiring-authentication)

Enable mutual auth for your application, all paths under the root of your app require a client certificate for access. To remove this requirement for certain paths, define exclusion paths as part of your application configuration.

1. From the left navigation of your app's management page, select **Configuration** > **General Settings**.
2. Next to **Client exclusion paths**, click the edit icon.
3. Click **New path**, specify a path, or a list of paths separated by `,` or `;`, and click **OK**.
4. Click **Save** at the top of the page.

In the following screenshot, any path for your app that starts with `/public` does not request a client certificate. Path matching is case-insensitive.

[image]

If you required to add multiple exclusion paths please give a feedback [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/feedback/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to invert the exclusions paths on the Azure App Service.  However, you can follow [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70230278/4764903) to have full flexibility of the paths that require a client certificate.

Comment: Hm, that would be ok. Can be solved via attributes or a middleware.
Last time I tried "Allow" it was the same as "Require" however. Found that strange